# Is there a way in C# Console Application to generate a QR code that show two or more URL on scanning

Tags: c#, qr-code

I have tried with barcode and QRCodeGenerator package in C# but I am able to add only 1 URL to the QR code at a time is there a way to display more than 1 URL on scan of 1 QR code in C#

NOTE: if possible I want the QRcode to be in anchor tag and should only display Google and YouTube ,on click of which it should redirect to that link
eg)

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/'>Google</a> <br />
<a href='https://www.youtube.com/'>youtube</a>
```

Expected output:
Google 
youtube

on click of Google or YouTube it should redirect to the site
Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course you can encode this in a QR Code (you can encode almost any text string), but the displayed result will depend on the decoding app

Comment: Since QR codes basically encode text, you can provide almost anything. Whether those links will be clickable depends on the scanning app. Many QR code readers simply show the encoded text instead of interpreting it. Therefore, if you use HTML in your QR code, you would need a QR code reader that interprets HTML.

Comment: Any idea on what those QR code reader apps would be . As I need the link to be redirected to that site (Would be helpful if you could provide me the app name for Android and IOS)..
Thanks in advance